# Sampling Precision, Jitter, and PID

Tags: discrete-signals, analog-to-digital, digital, digital-to-analog, pid

I am having difficulty understanding the effect of quantization noise and ADC resolution in a digital PID controller.
I am also trying to understand the effects of sampling jitter on a PID controller.

Can anyone recommend any materials to help me understand these issues in closed loop, digital systems?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's OK with the group to recommend one's own work, but here goes: the "Applied" part of [Applied Control Theory for Embedded Systems](https://www.elsevier.com/books/applied-control-theory-for-embedded-systems/wescott/978-0-7506-7839-1) covers this.  I would hope that modern 4th-year controls classes also cover this.

Comment: Fine with me, I appreciate the recommendation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating quantization noise as random noise is pretty well treated in the DSP literature.

Quantization in control systems usually exhibits as random noise, with $\sigma^2 = \frac 1 {12} q^2$, where $q$ is 1 LSB.  If the system is otherwise low noise, and if the quantization is coarse, then the quantization may create a limit cycle -- in this case, it acts like a square wave, 1 LSB peak-peak, being injected at the point of quantization and at the worst possible frequency.

Sampling jitter shows up when there's an input that's changing (think about it -- an unchanging input will give you the same sample, even if the sampling is uneven).  For an input $u(t)$, it acts like random noise *multiplied* by $\frac d {dt} u(t)$.  As such it's a nonlinear phenomenon -- if you're lucky, you can quantify it as a worst-case phenomenon (i.e., worst case is when $\frac d {dt} u(t)$ is as high as can be; if sampling jitter isn't a problem at that rate of change, it never will be).

Comment: I see many ADC datasheets providing a histogram that characterizes the variation in the ADC's output code with the inputs connected together (differential) or connected to a known DC voltage or grounded (single-ended). My understanding, built largely from TI guidance, is that the standard deviation shown for this distribution is a decent approximation to both the quantization noise and thermal noise in the ADC. Is that right?

Comment: It depends on the ADC -- but most ADCs these days are designed to have quantization noise smaller than thermal noise, at which point you can ignore quantization effects.  These days you need to pay attention to quantization if you have some sensor (or, even less likely) driver that inherently quantizes.